# how to use css to recover overflow scroll behavior

Tags: html, css

I was wondering what I would need to do with the div#blocker in this code to recover the ability to have overflow in "innermost" be handled with scrolling: https://jsfiddle.net/39q78tdm/ .

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  background: pink;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}

container {
  background: yellow;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}

#inner {
  background: aqua;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="blocker">
    <container>
      <header>header in container</header>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="inner">
          innermost
        </div>
      </div>
    </container>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: please be clear what you want. you want to add the scroll bar only if the content is overflowing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#blocker` is causing the whole element's height from being expanded. As a result, the whole `container` is being displayed in full height (824px) as well.

This can be fixed by setting `#blocker` to have the same height as `main`.

The other change that I've made is not really necessary in this context but by doing `calc(100% - headerHeight)`, I can make sure that the whole content in `#inner` can be shown. If you do not do this, the most bottom part of the content may be cut off as they are outside the black border being hidden by `main`'s `overflow: hidden`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
  background: pink;
  height: 400px;
  border: solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#blocker {
  height: 400px;
}
container {
  background: yellow;
}
#wrapper {
  height: calc(100% - 24px);
  overflow: scroll;
}
#inner {
  background: aqua;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="blocker">
    <container>
      <header>header in container</header>
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="inner">
          innermost
        </div>
      </div>
    </container>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use height in #wrapper id like below

```
#wrapper {
 overflow: scroll;
 height: 100px;
}
```